# Some problems to understand html attribute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="AddEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width:840px;margin-left:-420px">
</div>
```

help me to understnd why -1 is used in tabindex value and when should we use -1 as tabindex value?

Answer (score 2):

It's most probably in there as a workaround for a bug in IE. Quote from http://24ways.org/2009/html5-tool-of-satan-or-yule-of-santa/ :

*However, tabindex="-1" is a legal value in HTML5 as it allows for the element to be programmatically focussable by JavaScript. It’s also very useful for correcting a bug in Internet Explorer when used with a keyboard; in-page links go nowhere if the destination doesn’t have a proprietary property called hasLayout set or a tabindex of -1.*

Comment: `Some you can use now, and by the end of 2010 I predict you’ll be able to use a whole lot more` wow! blast from the past ... and an accurate prediction ;)